# How to avoid no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, vue.js, keycloak, quasar

I have a webapp that is running on NGINX and it is secured with Keycloak. After successfully sign in through the Keycloak login, it redirects me to the webapp as expected.

However, when I look into the web browser console it shows the following error messages:

[image]

The `Web Origins` is configured as:

[image]

How to avoid the error message? Do I miss any configuration on NGINX?

**Hint**, the webapp is developed by https://quasar.dev/.

Comment: `databaker.io` is the one that needs to add the CORS header, not you.  The resource you access is the one that needs to state it is OK for you to access the resource, you don't get to tell the server you want to access that it is OK for you to access it.

Comment: I also the owner of the `databaker.io` domain. So do I need the configure the NGINX server?

Comment: You have to configure whatever powers `databaker.io` such that it tells a user's browser that it is OK for a given domain to access a resource.  If that is NGINX, then yes.  If `databaker.io` doesn't send back a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, the browser will throw the error.

Comment: Could you plesae show me, who to configure the NGINX for CORS.

Comment: Asking for tutorials on how to do something is too broad a question for this site.  Search for topics on configuration, attempt them, come back and ask another question if you run into issues, or possibly ask [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) when you run into issues since server configuration is more their domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't configure Keycloak OIDC client correctly, so Keycloak didn't set proper CORS headers.

`https://dev.oidc.databaker.io/*` is not valid origin (`/*` at the end is a problem). `https://dev.oidc.databaker.io` is correct origin. But you will see that different origin was used, when you check error from the browse console. It looks like `https://dev.databaker.io` was used. So configure web origin of used Keycloak OIDC client properly and CORS issue should be solved.